# How to overwrite Image using GD library in PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I am using following code:

```
$source = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);   
imagerotate($source, $degrees);         
imagepng ( $rotated, $fileLocation, $quality);
```

But if an image already exists,imagepng return false means function doesn't overwrite the file.

How can I overwrite the existing file?
Thanks

Comment: May be destroy old image and create new image would be a good practice

Comment: But if i delete the image and new will not be created thn, i might lost the image without new one?

Comment: If you're worried about that then save it with a new filename, delete the old one and rename the new filename to the old filename.

Comment: Another way to do so?

Comment: imagepng should overwrite existing file - unless apache user does not have permission to edit on the existing file. I would check the existing file permissions.

Comment: existing file permission is 644

Comment: make it 666 (writeable for all users) and test it. Better yet give full permissions 777 and see what happens. then you can decide appropriate permission. if images were saved by apache, then it wouldn't be a problem in the first place.

Comment: i have used chmod but it return false may be due to group or owner issue?

Comment: what do you mean it return false? chmod 777 filename.jpg, then try the script for this specific file (re-upload it for testing) and see how it is working. Then take necessary action.

Comment: @smozgur I think he means that `imagepng` returns false. OP, could you please enable errors to see whether you're getting a notice telling you what's going on? Also, `fileLocation` is not the same as `filepath`. What have you set `$quality` to? You also never create `$rotated` at all.

Comment: @h2ooooooo OP said "if an image already exists", so I passed all the other possible problems in the code assuming it works if image doesn't exist and suggested it is a file permission problem. I agree that actual error should be monitored and act accordingly.